How prevalent was Shabbat observance in ancient times?
Elon Gilad, a writer at Haaretz, recently wrote a book "The Secret History of the Jews" (in Hebrew). I have not read the book, but have read various derivative works of his book.
He claims that Shabbat observance was only practiced after the Babylonian exile, and not during/after the exodus. He brings examples such as Nechemia (15:22) who observed that Jews didn't keep Shabbat. Or Yirmiyahu (17:23) where Jews would refuse to keep Shabbat. He claims that books written in the Temple periods there is no evidence of a weekly day of rest i.e., people go about their daily lives as normal, there is no preparation for Shabbat or observance of it, people aren't criticized for breaking Shabbat, and armies don't exploit the strategic weakness.
I will note that generally the Torah itself mentions the six days of work before rest, motif. Gilad claims that this was inserted at a later stage, or simply never observed in the first place...
He further claims that when prophets mention Shabbat it is regularly paired with ideas surrounding the new moon. He claims that in Babylonian "sabbatu" meant the day of the new moon. Gilad asserts that Jews practiced celebrations of the new moon (beginning of the month, rosh chodesh) and 'Shabbat' which was originally the middle of the month. Gilad then claims that only after the Babylonian exile did the monthly celebration transform into the weekly day of rest that it is today.
Leaving aside the Babylonian claims (I am not asking about comparative religion or appropriation), is there any evidence in Jewish scriptures that 'Shabbat' can be understood as a monthly observance (or that there was an observance of something in the middle of the month), or a weekly day of rest but was generally not observed by the masses up until the Babylonian exile?

Cf. the Metzad Chashvyahu Ostracon which speaks about a man working before Shabbat (though some have proposed other interpretations of the word).

I looked at the chapter where he discusses Shabbat and his argument is based on how in many cases Shabbat is mentioned together with the Chodesh (חדש/חודש), which often means the first of the month. Therefore Shabbat must have the same meaning as the Chodesh.

Many holidays (which are also called shabbat) fall on round numbers in the lunar month, could be related. But honestly if youre willing to just assert whole verses are later interpolations you can get to any meaning you want.

Adducing instances of Jews violating laws as evidence that those laws were not normative is specious reasoning.

@Fred correct. I wanted to avoid his reasons and focus on the questions. The rest is merely context, whether you agree with him or dont. There was an article i read a while ago regarding mikvah-going where it also only showed evidence of mikvah building significantly late in Jewish history, and evidence that taharah generally wasn't widely practiced. But absence of evidence isnt...

@bondonk Not much can be inferred from archeological finds of prevalent dedicated mikva baths beginning in Hasmonean times. Various bodies of water can be used for immersion. There's textual evidence for washing via ritual immersion prior to Second Temple times (note, for instance, in the story of Na'aman, the interchangeability of וְרָחַצְתָּ and וַיִּטְבֹּל), and compelling exegesis applying this to a nidda (including a binyan av that immersion is a general condition for purification, a kal vachomer from tum'as maga', and an inference from the peculiar phrasing "וְהַדָּוָה בְּנִדָּתָהּ").

The title should be "History of Erev Rav" by Chakham baLaila Elon Gilad. Under such a title, one can connect the dots. It's like discussion that Esav started at the moment of burial of Yaakov Avinu. We can discuss this till the end of days.

Just because he claims something doesn't mean it's true. Lots of fools have made up their own facts over time about Judaism to make themselves feel better about their empty lives. This is just another fool.

This sounds like another modern Academic theory that picks and chooses which parts of Tanach it wants to accept as true and reflective of their time and which parts are not. That type of motivated reasoning and special pleading can support any theory. It's silly.
Yirmiyahu isn't post-exilic. It is prophecies from the end of the First Temple period. And the people are being criticized for carrying and doing work on Shabbos (Jeremiah 17:19-23.)
We have archeological evidence that Numbers was written pre-exilic (the Ketef Hinnom scrolls) and Numbers discusses the prohibition of doing work on the Shabbos day and the special Shabbos sacrifices that follow in sequence from daily sacrifices to monthly (Rosh Chodesh) with Shabbos in between.
II Kings 11:4-8 takes place long before the exile and references the weekly switching of of the mishmoros of Kohanim and Leviim as the בָּאֵ֣י הַשַּׁבָּ֔ת and the יֹצְאֵ֣י הַשַּׁבָּ֑ת (the same terms used in Divrei Hayamim to describe the weekly mishmoros). This strongly indicates that Shabbos is a weekly event.
There are also other places in Neviim that mention Shabbos without the chodesh. E.g. Isaiah 56:4, 6; II Kings 16:18.
There is no reason to think Shabbos was ever anything but a weekly special day, just like it is today.

Though I agree with you, note that Gilad explicitly referenced all or most of the verses you cited and simply dismissed them in various ways.

"We have archeological evidence that Deuteronomy was written pre-exilic" - what is that?

@Harel13 I haven't read his work. But I have read arguments like this. It makes their claims unfalsifiable. They highlight the verses that they based their thesis on and they dismiss the verses that disprove the thesis. It is so intellectually weak.

@ba I was referring to the Ketef Hinnom scrolls. But I misremembered. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketef_Hinnom_scrolls
They have verses from Numbers, not Deuteronomy. But the same argument applies. Shabbos is mentioned in Numbers too (e.g. 15:32).  I will edit the answer. Thanks.

I don't understand, because the Neviim were not criticising people for not keeping Shabbos, that means they didn't have Shabbos?
Or does he assume there were always Chilonim?
Off the top of my head I know Shabbos is mentioned in Yeshayahu (not off the top of my head, it's perek 58), we learn things from there.
But maybe that was added later? Maybe anything I can possibly say was added later?
Maybe all mentions of Israel were added later. Anything you want.
The Yirmiyahu passuk sounds in context like it's pre-destruction of the Beit Hamikdash. If not, and he's saying Shabbos was added only post-destruction, that would give a very short timeline for such a major mitzva to be added, accepted, not kept, and we be rebuked for not keeping it.
Edit: Some more points on what you quote.
"people go about their daily lives as normal, there is no preparation for Shabbat or observance of it" What exactly does he expect? Is every detail of daily life described and only this is missing?
"and armies don't exploit the strategic weakness"
A. That's coming form the point of view that there is no God watching over us.
B. There are shomer Shabbos soldiers and security personnel still today. Pikuach nefesh.

Good point - doesn't the fact that the nevi'im are criticising some for not keeping Shabbat imply that it is expected that they should be, and have been "until recently"?

It is halachically permitted to defend against an invasion on Shabbos, or to continue an offensive siege on Shabbos (as in the story of Yehoshua and Yericho, which was permitted based on D'varim 20:20). Elon Gilad's military argument is based on ignorance of the parameters of Shabbos observance.

To add to this (excellent) answer, the only Shabbos violation that Yirmiyahu accuses them of is carrying on Shabbos. Which is a מלאכה גרועה, something that we would hardly even think qualifies as a melachah if the Torah hadn't told us so, and one which is very easy to violate inadvertently. If anything, that's evidence that they were keeping Shabbos for the most part, and just being careless with this one detail. (On top of which, in Yerushalayim the whole issue may be only derabanan anyway, since technically it was a karmelis.)
